# render an array of object from the store in my component and change value in the object when onPress is called using a dispatcher

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

So I have a dummy data that is an array of object as an initial state. each object has a value of id, name, and checked(boolean and initially false). I have an action that map through this object and change the checked value to true given the item.id. Then in my component, I rendered these objects as a touchableOpacity using map then onPress dispatch an that action. I put a console.log(item.id, 'is', item.checked) to see if the value of checked changes but it just keeps logging false.

The logic for changing the checked from false to true was first in the reducer so i moved it to the action but still it is not working.

This is the reducer,

```
const initialState = {
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      itemName: 'Plastic',
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      itemName: 'Papers',
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      itemName: 'Pet Bottle',
      checked: false,
    },
  ],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.checked,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

then my action is,

```
const toggleItemHelper = (items, itemId) => {
  items.map(item =>
    item.id === itemId ? {...item, checked: !item.checked} : item,
  );
};

export const toggleItemAction = itemId => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const items = getState().items;
  return dispatch({
    type: TOGGLE_ITEM,
    checked: toggleItemHelper(items, itemId),
  });
};
```

then my component is,

```
import {toggleItemAction} from '../../../../../redux/GarbageItem/action';

const GarbageItem = () => {
  const Icon = createIconSetFromFontello(fontelloConfig);
  const items = useSelector(state => state.garbageItem.items);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const toggleItem = itemId => dispatch(toggleItemAction(itemId));

  return (
    <View style={styles.garbageItemsContainer}>
      {items.map(item => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={item.id}
          style={styles.itemContainer}
          onPress={() => {
            toggleItem.bind(this, item.id);
            console.log(item.id, 'is', item.checked);
          }}>
          <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer}>
            <Text>
              <Icon
                name="uncheckedCheckBox"
                size={20}
                color={colors.gomiGray}
              />
            </Text>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.itemLabel}>{item.itemName}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default GarbageItem;
```

expected the console.log to show item.id, 'is', true when the touchableOpacity is pressed but then it keeps showing false no matter how many times I press it.

I actually got an advice that getState is anti-pattern so it would be amazing if I could change the value of checked in the useSelector then dispatch an action that would replace the old object with a updated one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by moving the logic of changing the checked: false to true in the component rather than doing it in the action.js :D

here's the new code now,

reducer,

```
const initialState = {
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      itemName: 'Plastic',
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      itemName: 'Papers',
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      itemName: 'Pet Bottle',
      checked: false,
    },
  ],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.newItems,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

action,

```
export const toggleItemAction = newItems => dispatch => {
  return dispatch({
    type: TOGGLE_ITEM,
    newItems,
  });
};
```

index.js

```
const GarbageItem = () => {
  const Icon = createIconSetFromFontello(fontelloConfig);
  const currentItems = useSelector(state => state.garbageItem.items);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const toggleItem = newItems => dispatch(toggleItemAction(newItems));

  const checkItem = (items, itemId) => {
    return items.map(item =>
      item.id === itemId ? {...item, checked: !item.checked} : item,
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.garbageItemsContainer}>
      {currentItems.map(item => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={item.id}
          style={styles.itemContainer}
          onPress={() => {
            const newItems = checkItem(currentItems, item.id);
            toggleItem(newItems);
            console.log(item.id, 'is', item.checked);
          }}>
          <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer}>
            <Text>
              <Icon
                name="uncheckedCheckBox"
                size={20}
                color={colors.gomiGray}
              />
            </Text>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.itemLabel}>{item.itemName}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```